# How can I run Gradle tests on a different machine without recompiling?

Tags: java, windows, testing, gradle

I am trying to set up a Windows test server to run the unit tests of a Java library project via SSH. The actual building happens on a Linux server.

As a consequence, I would like to be able to copy the pre-built project to the Windows machine and run `.\gradlew.bat test` on it **without** recompiling it. Since I’m copying the entire `src` and `build` folder, I was expecting Gradle to realise that the build artefacts are more recent than the sources, [and thus to avoid recompilation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24340017/1968).

However, Gradle *does* attempt to recompile the sources, and fails (there’s intentionally no JDK installed on the Windows machine, since *I don’t want to build on the Windows machine*):

> > Task :compileJava FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> * What went wrong:
> Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> > Could not find tools.jar. Please check that C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_251 contains a valid JDK installation.
> …

(`scp` does not preserve timestamps when copying from Linux to Windows, but I verified that the timestamps of the files in the `build` directory are newer than that of the `src` directory.)

Next I tried [removing the `compileTestJava` dependency](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/remove-task-dependency/18493) from `testClasses`, but [this is no longer supported as of Gradle 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59055441/gradle-build-removing-tasks-from-the-task-container-is-not-supported#comment104350574_59055441) (and I don’t think this would have worked anyway, and it seems like hack).

So:

- Why does Gradle think my project needs recompiling after copying it to a Windows machine, even thought the file modification timestamps seem ordered correctly (`build` is newer than `src` is newer than `build.gradle`)?
- **How can I ensure that Gradle does not attempt to rebuild up-to-date dependencies before running tests** after copying the project to a different (Windows) machine?

Here’s my `build.gradle` file (it‘s really quite barebone):

```
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java-library'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs = ["src/main/java"]
    test.java.srcDirs = ["src/test/java"]
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}

test {
    testLogging {
        outputs.upToDateWhen {false}
        showStandardStreams = true
    }
}
```

Here’s how I kick off the build from the Linux server (copying the individual files/directories manually one after the other to ensure well-ordered timestamps makes no difference):

```sh
ssh test@win 'rmdir /Q /S Workspace\test' || :
ssh test@win 'mkdir Workspace\test'
scp -r build.gradle gradle gradlew.bat src build test@win:Workspace\\test
ssh test@win 'cd Workspace\test & .\gradlew.bat --no-daemon test'
```

---

Why not just install the JDK and build on the Windows server?

The Windows machine is resource-constrained (it’s also a VM). Furthermore, the build needs to happen *anyway* on the Linux server. I would really like to avoid a slow and redundant rebuild.

Why not test on the Linux server (using Wine)?

I tried that, but our Linux library uses some Win32 APIs (via cross-compiled JNI) which Wine doesn’t support, and which reproducibly lead to a hang.

Further notes:

- I want to run the default `test` task, not [custom tests](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28607291/1968).

Comment: But... Your tests aren't written in Java ? Also, are you using [build cache](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_cache.html) ? Even if so, maybe Gradle needs to launch compile task to make some checks ?

Comment: @amanin No, my tests are written in Java using JUnit and also compiled on the Linux machine and copied over. I’m not using build caching. — “maybe Gradle needs to launch compile task to make some checks” … I *thought* it doesn’t, but I fear you might be right. I’m installing the JDK now to test this.

Comment: Yes but, to execute them, you need java anyway. I don't understand how it would work without java installed. Gradle is telling you that no valid *jre* was found. You cannot execute java binaries without jre.

Comment: @amanin Java *is* correctly installed (otherwise Gradle wouldn’t run at all). It’s the *JDK* that’s missing (and the Gradle error message is telling me that it’s not finding a *JDK* installation in the `JAVA_HOME` path, which is correctly set to `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_251`).

Comment: @amanin Tested that now; but Gradle really does recompile the project once I’ve pointed it to a valid JDK installation. It doesn’t just run `compileJava` to make checks.

Comment: Ok. Have you tried to [define a custom local build cache](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55381607/2678097) then copying it to the windows machine ?

Answer (score 0):

A regrettably hand-wavy answer here:  this seems to be accomplishable through the use of [build caches](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_cache.html).  The caveat is, that from everything that I can see on Gradle's site, this is either:

- a function of their Gradle Enterprise offering, or
- something that can be leveraged [with their Docker container](https://hub.docker.com/r/gradle/build-cache-node/), which is heavily limited because they probably want you to pay for it.

Once a build cache is configured (and I don't believe it prudent to copy the [instructions on how to configure one verbatim here](https://docs.gradle.com/build-cache-node/)), it seems that it's a matter of leveraging it in your build script.

(from https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_cache.html#sec:build_cache_configure_remote):

settings.gradle:

```
buildCache {
    remote(HttpBuildCache) {
        url = 'https://example.com:8123/cache/'
    }
}
```

According to the [relevant documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_cache.html#sec:task_output_caching_details), the `compileJava` task is cacheable so no further configuration in the build is required for it.